# spring java configuration unit test

Tags: spring

I am trying out spring's java configuration. While using xml config files my unit tests use to have the following

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(....)
```

If I am using java configuration, How do i do it. or should I just use

```
ApplicationContext appConfig = new  AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SimpleConfiguration.class);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As of Spring 3.1, @ContextConfiguration now has full support for @Configuration classes; no XML required.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#d0e1392

Or more specifically, http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#testcontext-ctx-management-javaconfig, which shows the following code snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
// ApplicationContext will be loaded from AppConfig and TestConfig
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
public class MyTest {
    // class body...
}
```

`AppConfig` and `TestConfig` are @Configuration classes (aka "Java config" classes in @user373201's comments)

Comment: Don't see a relevance to my question. I wanted to know how to use @ContextConfiguration while using Java config classes

Comment: Is it possible to use the same Java config classes that are used in the source code, or should the files be duplicated and put in the test folder?

Answer (score 3):

@ContextConfiguration is used to load the Spring configurations while you are working with test cases . If you don't need it , you could use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext to load the Spring configuration .

Use the [constructor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.0.2/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29) which takes in configuration locations as String array .

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext is used to auto detect the annotated classes . I don't think it can be used to load configuration files . It is similar to context:component-scan

[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) provides Spring Test support for Junit via annotations like @Test.

Comment: can you provide an example as to how I can use @ContextConfiguration with Java config classes

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Java config classes ? Please provide a sample.